# Randomly one morning Pioneer after market stereo started to only have sound when in reverse

Tags: audio

I have a 2007 Toyota corolla that has an aftermarket pioneer stereo head unit with a 5 channel amp and a reverse camera.everything was working correctly for the past 6 months and a few days ago I tried to play a song and no more sound, later I realized that it does have sound still but only when the car is in reverse... Nothing has been done to change or àlter any of the system or wiring. The unit works as normal when not in reverse it just does not have any sound unless in reverse. I have had all of this system working properly for over 6 months with no issues. I have checked the fuses, factory reset the unit, checked the wiring and can't seem to find an ussue, and since both the head unit and amp have power when the car is in any gear makes me believe that that it would be an assume with a speaker wire, but after realizing that the sound does work how it's supposed to while the car is in reverse only...so that would confirm that my speakers are wired correctly... Any ideas on how to fix this or what to try next? The speakers and sub are all ran with rca cables if that makes any difference or not?

Update -

The head units model number is: Pioneer DMH-160BT The amps model number is: Boss audio systems PV3700 5 channel. Nothing has been added or messed with recently for it to do this other then the trunk being open and closed, everything worked on my way home from work and the next morning no sound, it's not wired to my reverse either I did pull it and look to check for a loose connections or wrong connections, yes there is a reverse camera that has always been hooked up and that still works correctly, and yes all the speakers are ran threw the amp and RCA cables each on it's own separate channel and speaker wires in the wire harness are all capped off on both the cars factory end and the head units wire harness. I will check the ground wire as maybe it got moved to much or has come loose over time.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Did the sound used to go off when reverse was selected, which is normal for some stereos?

Comment: Can you add the model number of the stereo?

Comment: Have you had anything added recently like a reversing camera? Speakers don’t stop working and then only work in reverse, are all your speakers coming from the amp? It’s possible someone has powered your amp from the reverse switch but again I suspect maybe you’ve had something fitted recently for the wiring to be buggered up

Comment: @DanK It is possible that a ground connection has broken somewhere that the speakers require.  When reverse is selected the reverse switch grounds a wire.  This may then be providing the ground that the speakers require.

Comment: Could a speaker wire have a ground issue or would it be just the amps ground wire?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.